# Postman - use CSV as input

Tags: csv, postman

I am using Postman to test a microservice and I was wondering if you can do something like this.

- have a collection with 2 GET request (request1, request2) that have
  as one of the headers - userId
- have a CSV file with two values for userId: test1, test2
- run the collection using the CSV file like this: request1 uses the userId= test1 and request2 uses the parameter userId=test2

I know you can run the collection so that it iterates for each value in the CSV file through each request, but I would like to to map each request to a value in the CSV file. is this possible? If yes, how can you do that?

Answer (score 0):

CSV files are only accepted as a iteration data files, so

> is this possible to map each request to a value in the CSV file.

answer is: No, you can't.

You should give us more detailed question, but I feel that [this link](https://thisendout.com/2017/02/22/loops-dynamic-variables-postman-pt2/)
will be helpful.
Also you can use JSON as datafile instead of CSV and make such construction:

Firstly, set environment variable "count" to 0.

JSON:

```
[
   {
    "UserIdHeadersValue":
     [
      "firstvalue",
      "secondValue",
      "thirdValue"
     ]
    }
]
```

And in Scripts:

pre-request:

```
var count = parseInt(pm.variables.get("count"));
pm.variables.set("headerValue", data.UserIdHeaderValue[count]);
//you can put now that header value using {{headerValue}};
pm.environment.set("count", count+1);
```